# How to fix this SQL query?

Tags: sql

I try to write a query that check the reserve slots in the database and check the capacity of restaurant. The query is:

```
Select COUNT(r.capacity<rs.no_people) As people;

SELECT `r.restaurant_id`
, `r.restaurant_name`
, `r.capacity`
, `rs.no_of_people`
, `rs.date`
, `rs.start_time`
, `rs.end_time`
FROM `restaurant`AS r,reservation AS rs
Where r.restaurant_id=rs.restaurant_id
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not giving you the results you want? If not, what results are you looking for?

Comment: Is capacity the number of people a restaurant can take, or the number of tables it has?  Can we assume each reservation is one table?  Simply counting people may show that a restaurant has space even though all tables are occupied, unless you're willing to seat strangers at the same table.

Comment: This question isn't clear, so voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `r.restaurant_id`, `r.restaurant_name`, `r.capacity`,    
`rs.no_of_people`, `rs.date`, `rs.start_time`, `rs.end_time`
, (`r.capacity` - `rs.no_of_people`) as new_column
FROM `restaurant` r JOIN reservation rs
ON `r.restaurant_id` = `rs.restaurant_id`
```

First of all, the two tables have to be `join`ed. Then you take the difference of `capacity` and `no.of.people`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply want to check for available seats during a specific time interval:

```
SELECT r.*, r.capacity - SUM(rs.people) AS available
FROM restaurant r
LEFT JOIN reservation rs ON r.restaurant_id = rs.restaurant_id
                        AND <date> = rs.date
                        AND <start_time> < rs.end_time
                        AND <end_time> > rs.start_time
GROUP BY r.restaurant_id
```

Replace `<date>`, `<start_time>` and `<end_time>` with the relevant values.  If reservations can span midnight/different days, you may need to adjust your table design and query.

Comment: please tell me <date> ,<start_time> and <end_time> belongs to which table

Comment: I intended those as parameters you pass in from the user/interface, not stored values.

Comment: Like this? but this check the availability of this specific date and and time . right? but if user enter other than this than it will work?                                                                                                                                       LEFT JOIN reservation rs ON r.restaurant_id = rs.restaurant_id
                   AND 7/30/2015 = rs.date
                  AND 2:00 = rs.end_time
                  AND 3:00 = rs.start_time
                  GROUP BY r.restaurant_id

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying in your last two comments.